# mysql server has gone away in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, ping, reconnect

I am running my php script and getting an intermittent issue:

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2013 Lost connection to MySQL server during query'

Is it possible to ping mysql in PDO if such error occurs?

I just want to bring this in your notice that my PDO connection is not persistent. I am connecting PDO in loop. I suppose every time a new connection will open up in loop. If this is so, then why mysql is losing connection? Or it may possible that if a PDO connection already exists then it gives the existing pdo object. but if such error occurs, it should try to reconnect and give the new connection instead of error.

Any possible solution to avoid the error?

Comment: TRY and catch seems legit . .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case, PDO was taking single connection and if the loop size is big, connection was getting timed out. So, I increased the timeout of PDO connection for all cli's.

```
$this->connection = new PDO($this->dsn, $this->username, $this->password);
//Increase the session time out for all cli's
if(php_sapi_name() == 'cli'){
      $query = $this->connection->prepare("set session wait_timeout=10000,interactive_timeout=10000,net_read_timeout=10000");
      $query->execute();
}
```

Issue is resolved now.

Comment: Was using Boris as a CLI to do testing, and hitting this issue.  The above resolved it for me - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest running the database queries within a try..catch block, like so:

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
    // Do something here
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage();
    die();
}
```

Comment: I am already handling exceptions while connecting with my db.
        function connect() {
          try {
               $this->connection = new PDO($this->dsn, $this->username, $this->password);
           } catch (PDOException $e) {
                 throw new jsDatabaseException($e->getMessage() . '[dsn: ' . $this->dsn . ']');
                }
           
                        $this->connection->setAttribute(PDO_ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO_ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
       }

Comment: You need use try-catch for all database queries, not just the connection. That way if you do a select or update and the database connection has gone away - it will throw an exception, and you can catch it and probably reconnect or something.

Comment: Similar problem here.
In my script I issue a CALL to a SP then a SELECT.
While the CALL was running in short time it used to work fine. Now the SP is taking about 60 secs.
The SP finishes without errors (processing about 800K rows), but it seems is taking too much time for PHP.
Limiting the SP to process 1000 rows returns in 0.3 secs and the script continues flawless.
It looks it's just a matter of time with the driver (PDO)
Anyone have a clue?